# modify global variable value based condition with in a function in python

Tags: python, global-variables

I am declaring global variables before i run the user defined function.

```
global x
x=2
```

**Now I want to change the value of the global variable based on some conditions with in the function it throws UnboundLocalError.**

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

i am changing the value of  global variable as follows.

```
if pd.isnull(x):
   x=1
```

The above code i used in user defined function.

Anyone can help me to tackle this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i didn't get a solution from your reference question .If you don't mind can you please read the question clearly.

Comment: i got solution for my question,  
globals()['x']=1
can you remove my question from duplicates.if you understand my problem.